# Inner indent on bullet points <li>

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm having a issue with the indent on the right side of the bullet points

I have added a snippet of code and an image that pretty much explains its self

[image: Image1]

```html
 <h1 style="display: block;margin: 0;padding: 0;color: #000000;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 26px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 125%;letter-spacing: normal;text-align: left;"><span style="font-size:28px"><strong><span style="color:#96c11f">Why now</span></strong></span></h1>    
<ul>
<li><span style="font-size:16px">Increase in buyers looking for businesses over the Christmas period.</span></li>
<li><span style="font-size:16px">More sales agreed in January so be on the market in time.</span></li><br>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is your css code and ul?

Comment: I cannot see a problem in the graphic you show. The problems I do see you are having is that you are using rubbish code and invalid HTML.

Comment: li {
margin:0px !important;
padding:0px !important;
}​

Comment: Im currently not using a ul, its one of the tests ive tried to get rid of it

Comment: `li` is only allowed in `ul` and `ol`.

Comment: The problem is to the right of the bullet point there is a gap

Comment: In your code example there's no bullets at all.

Comment: there is clearly 2 bullet points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing the margin of the `li` to bring the bullet to the left and increasing/decreasing its `padding` to suit the distance you want between bullet and text.

```css
h1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 125%;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #96c11f;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding:0;
  margin-top:0;
}
ul li{
  margin-left:1em;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Why now</h1> 
<ul>
  <li>Increase in buyers looking for businesses over the Christmas period.</li>
  <li>More sales agreed in January so be on the market in time.</li>
  <br>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi mate just to confirm this is the space im having problems with http://imgur.com/a/mFUPz

Comment: @AlexBanerjee got that (*after a while*). Reducing/setting to 0 the `padding-left` of the `li` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you are written invalid html format,you can write `<li>` only inside of `<ol>` or `<ul>` tag.if you are trying to remove the white space before the `<li>` you can use the following methods.

```
li { **display:flex;** }
```

```css
li{
  display:flex;
  }
```

```html
<h1 style="display: block;margin: 0;padding: 0;color: #000000;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 26px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 125%;letter-spacing: normal;text-align: left;"><span style="font-size:28px"><strong><span style="color:#96c11f">Why now</span></strong></span></h1> 
<li><span style="font-size:16px">Increase in buyers looking for businesses over the Christmas period.</span>
</li>
<li style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;"><span style="font-size:16px">More sales agreed in January so be on the market in time.</span>
</li>
<br>
```

or li { **display:block; float:left;** }

```css
li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
  }
```

```html
<h1 style="display: block;margin: 0;padding: 0;color: #000000;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 26px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 125%;letter-spacing: normal;text-align: left;"><span style="font-size:28px"><strong><span style="color:#96c11f">Why now</span></strong></span></h1> 
<li><span style="font-size:16px">Increase in buyers looking for businesses over the Christmas period.</span>
</li>
<li style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;"><span style="font-size:16px">More sales agreed in January so be on the market in time.</span>
</li>
<br>
```